# How to redirect www. to non-www and http to https without 3 server blocks?

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

This is what I've got right now...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.domain.com .old-domain.com;
    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;

    ###################
    ## SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;

    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/private/dhparam.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /srv/mpen/public;

    include restrictions.conf;
    include php.conf;

    # ... EXTRA_STUFF_HERE ...

    ###################
    ## SSL

    # https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/nginx-configuration-sample/2173

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;

    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
    # Generate with:
    #   openssl dhparam -out /etc/ssl/private/dhparam.pem 2048
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/private/dhparam.pem;

    # Copied from https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS. 7776000 seconds = 90 days which is how long letsencrypt certs last
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;

    # OCSP Stapling ---
    # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    # If you want to specify a DNS resolver for stapling, you can uncomment the below
    # line. If you leave it commented, nginx will use your system resolver, which will probably
    # work just fine!
    #resolver <IP DNS resolver>;
}
```

But I don't like have to repeat all my SSL cert info for `https:/www.domain.com`. Is there any way to merge some of these server blocks to remove the redundancies?

To recap, here's what I want:

```
http://domain.com -> https://domain.com
http:/www.domain.com -> https://domain.com
https://domain.com -> (no redirect necessary)
https://www.domain.com -> https://domain.com
```

Comment: Put them into http and they will be the same for all servers. Or use `include`

Comment: @AlexeyTen I don't know hwat you mean by "put them into http"? I didn't think about `include` -- I could use that to remove the repeated SSL info at least.

Comment: `http` is the root element of config. You could decare SSL-related directives in `http` context. Usually by putting them in some file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` directory, but it depends on OS

Comment: @AlexeyTen Oh...but then that would apply to all domains wouldn't it? I can't have that.

Comment: Yes. If it's a problem, then stick to solution with `include`.